# How make web3 work on?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, docker

Sorry for noob question.
I installed web3 (npm install web3),

but for some reason instead of calling web3 methods or showing object data, nodejs displays object structure:

```
> web3.eth.accounts
Accounts {
  currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
  _requestManager:
   RequestManager {
     provider:
      HttpProvider {
```

when I connect to geth via geth attach, web3 embedded into geth works correctly

I am trying to use web3 from inside docker, Dockerfile is below:

```
FROM node:carbon

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app


# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install vim

RUN npm install

RUN npm install express

RUN npm install nodemon -g

RUN npm install hashmap && \
    npm install body-parser -g

# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production



# Bundle app source
COPY . .


CMD [ "nodemon", "start" ]
```

Comment: I can't tell without seeing your `package.json`, but I'm guessing you're using web3.js 1.0.0-beta in your docker instance, while `geth` uses web3.js 0.2x.x. `web3.eth.getAccounts()` probably does what you want.

Comment: Web3.js methods return promises(in the new 1.0.0 beta), they are not the same as web3 api inside geth. Check the web3.js docs for examples

Comment: yeah, package.json states that web3 is 1.0.0-beta.30:
 {
  "name": "ess_emulator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js on Docker",
  "author": "Oleg Levchenko <oleg.levchenko@ooma.com>",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.0.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "hashmap": "^2.3.0",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.30"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me:

```
> web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log)
```

As per documentation: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getaccounts

Answer (score 0):

Try add `await` keyword on your code. Like:

```
await web3.eth.accounts
```

You are adding this, because: web3 returns a Promise. You can search what is promises in javascript.